# Oracle Query to display using partition by

Tags: oracle

input table is

**eno ename sal**

```
10 satish   1000
20 soujanya 1300
10 satish   2000
20 soujanya 1500
```

output table like

**emp ename sal**

```
10 satish   3000
20 soujanya 2800
```

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] before posting a question. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hint: assuming that your your example wrong ( `1500` instead of `15000`) you may need to `group by` some columns and get the `sum` of another one

Comment: just `1300+1500 = 2800` , so here: `15000` last zero is typo ?

Comment: Most of the beginner online SQL tutorials cover basic uses of GROUP BY and when it is used. A very basic bit of research yourself would get an answer to this that would help you beyond this basic question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need this:

```
select eno, ename, sum(sal)   from t group by eno, ename
```

Answer (score 0):

### try this

```
select eno, ename, sum(sal) over (partition by eno order by ename)   from t
```